# How to disable dropping and creating views and functions when publishing database project?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, database-project

When I publish Visual Studio database project targeting SQL Server 2012 it generates script containing drop views and functions statements and then creating these views and functions, although there are no changes in these views and functions in DB project at all comparing to database. How can I disable this behavior? 
I would like to have publish output equal to what I get when I generate script after schema compare (project to database), so only affect objects for which there are changes.

Answer (score 3):

Are you absolutely sure that there are no differences? Even a difference in the "NOT FOR REPLICATION" options can cause issues. Do a compare of the live database against your project and see what is different (Tools - SQL - Compare Schema). If there are differences, fix them. Otherwise, you shouldn't be seeing anything to actually change.  As Keith noted, check to make sure you don't have the "always re-create" option enabled. That could be giving you trouble, though it doesn't usually drop individual items, but the entire database.  You may also want to check collations - if those are different you could have issues.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "Always re-create database" option is unchecked in the Advanced publish settings.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the reason for why SSDT thought the scheme was different I think is the first point of call. SQL Scheme compare is your friend here. (In VS under Tools => SQL => New Scheme Comparison...)

Computed column definitions and constraint definitions were definitely candidates, as was potentially column ordering. Ironically I did have one issue with a computed column but it was not the definition, it was the fact that I didn't add NOT NULL to the end of the column definition (which is the default of course) but SSDT saw that as different everytime.